# Call of super.method automatically

Tags: java, abstract-class, superclass

Is it possible to call the super method from abstract class automatically when this overridden Method be called.

**Like this:**

```
 abstract class A {

  protected void doSomeThing() {
    // do default Code
  }
}

class B extends A {

  @Override
  protected void doSomeThing() {
    // Here should super.doSomeThing automatically called

    // do some thing else
  }
}
```

If this possible,i would be happy for a little example to explain how i can do that.

Comment: It's not possible. All overridden methods must explicitly call superclass methods, if needed.

Comment: The best you can do it raise some kind of flag if the super method is called, and error or something if it's not called by some point.  A bit hacky though.

Comment: I googled your exact question title and the linked duplicate was the first result.

Comment: @Michael i have seen the duplicate Question. The marked Answer isn't that what i want and the Question is 6 years old, so it could be solved in other way

Comment: You should mention all research in your question. The fact that the marked answer is not what you want does not disqualify your question as a duplicate. The fact that it's old is also, in this case, irrelevant. The language hasn't changed in that regard.